# Product image border colour dependent on product category

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have a site where each product image has a 1px solid border. The colour of the border is currently black. However, I would like the colour of the border to be definied by the category; for example all products with the parent category 'blue' should have a blue border, and all products with the parent category 'red' should have a red border and so on.

Is this achievable in Magento? I know the body tag of the page is given a unique CSS reference but I want the product image border colour to be defined by the top level category, not the child of that category.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: You want to an listing page or Individual page

Comment: add one attribute text (colour) in category admin side and this attribute colour code value use in fronted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have 100 sub-categories within a specific category you can apply the specific border color to the parent category at once. Let's say you have a category with 100+ sub-categories. Magento will add a .categorypath-living-subcategoryname css class to each sub-category. So each sub-category name is added to the .categorypath class. In this case you can use a CSS wild card to select the first part of the concatenated CSS class. Example can be found here: [Using CSS wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/match-all-class-selectors-that-begin-with)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to listing page you just check Body tag class name it automatically create class name based on category

```
<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-living-html category-living">
```

Here **category-living** is a category name so write a css

```
.catalog-category-view .category-living .category-products ul li img{border-color:green;}
.catalog-category-view.category-living-home .category-products ul li img{border-color:yellow;}
```

If it's Individual page

```
catalog-product-view .category-living-home .product-img-box .product-image{border-color:yellow;}

catalog-product-view .category-living .product-img-box .product-image{border-color:green;}
```

Or share your website link.

Comment: Thanks Kothari, but what about if I have a 100 sub-categories within 'living' - I wouldn't want to write 100 individual lines of code...as far as I can tell if this is the case Magento concatenates the body class, so it would become 'category-living-sub-cat-1' etc.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to add this functionality is to create a small module with an observer.  I'd observe something category related (maybe catalog_controller_category_init_after).

Have the observer determine if the page is a sub category page, then using the code below add the class of the parent category.

```
if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
    $root->addBodyClass('whatever');
}
```